# Is $P(a)$ logically equivalent to $\forall y [(y=a) \rightarrow P(y)]$?

Tags: logic, solution-verification, quantifiers

I am not entirely sure if my proof is correct. I would appreciate if somebody helped.

$(\rightarrow)$
Assume $P(a)$. Let an arbitrary $y$. Let $y=a$. Since $P(a)$ and $y=a$, then $P(y)$. Since $y$ is arbitrary, then $\forall y [(y=a) \rightarrow P(y)]$.

$(\leftarrow)$ Assume $\forall y [(y=a) \rightarrow P(y)]$. Then, by universal instantiation, $(a=a) \rightarrow P(a)$. Then, $P(a)$.

Since $P(a)$ is logically equivalent to $\forall y [(y=a) \rightarrow P(y)]$, then, assuming $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas, $\Gamma \rightarrow P(a)$ is equivalent to $\Gamma \rightarrow \forall y [(y=a) \rightarrow P(y)]$. If $y$ does not occur in $\Gamma$, then the statement is equivalent to $\forall y [\Gamma \rightarrow ((y=a) \rightarrow P(y))]$, which is the same as $\forall y [(\Gamma \land (y=a)) \rightarrow P(y)]$. Have I missed something? Thanks.

Comment: IMO, it's confusing to read "Let $y$ be arbitrary. Let $y = a$." Instead, "let $y$ be arbitrary. If $y<>a$, then the conditional holds. Otherwise, $y=a$" etc.

Comment: You mean, "if $y=a$, then condition holds"? I'm afraid I cannot make any claims from $y \neq a$. Either way, is the proof correct?

Comment: The implication ("conditional" or "if-then statement") holds if the antecedent ("if" part) is false.

Comment: But if a prove an implication assuming the antecedent as false, I am not verifying its validity. Validity requires that the antecedent is true.

Comment: yes, you do both since the whole implication must hold for all $y$ -- even $y$ different from $a$. But it does hold, for both $y<>a$ and $y=a$, but for different reasons.

Comment: Ned means you *do not have to* prove an implication with a false antecedent (the implication will always be true then).  You prove an implication *via* deriving its consequent under the *assumption* that its antecedent is true.

Comment: However, @TylerD007 *validity* does not require that the antecedent *is* true, just that the consequent must hold *when* it is.

Comment: In this concrete case, all I have is the assumption $P(a)$. I suposse I cannot derive anything assuming $y \neq a$... Either way, is the proof correct? I mean, is $P(a)$ equivalent to $\forall y [(y = a) \rightarrow P(y)]$?

Comment: Yes.  Suppose $P(a)$, then for arbitrary $y$, if $y=a$ then $P(y)$.  Therefore we deduce $P(a)\to\forall y~(y=a\to P(y))$. Conversely suppose $\forall y~(y=a\to P(y))$, then we may derive $P(a)$.

Comment: Thank you, Mr Kemp. I was afraid the proof would be wrong, since in this same site someone told me so.

Comment: The issue in "moving" from $\Gamma \vdash \ldots$ to $\Gamma \to \ldots$ is that $\Gamma$ is a set of formulas whatever, and thus it can be an infinite set. If $\Gamma$ is a *finite* set, than we can replace it with the conjunction of its elements. In this case we have a single formula and we can write $\alpha \to \ldots$, where $\alpha := \gamma_1 \land \ldots \land \gamma_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first proof is valid.

Semantically: $P(a)$ holds *exactly when* "anything that is $a$ satisfies $P$."

---

Your second is not quite correct.  $\Gamma$ cannot be a *set* of formula, rather it must be a *well formed formula* to be used the way you are using it.  Otherwise the proof is okay.